# Avoid redirection when reading html source from an Applet

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, jsoup

I have written a Java applet to read in the HTML from one of our intranet systems.

My code is as follows:

```
public static String getOrdersInProvisioning(){
    try{
        URL url = new URL("https://www.internalsystem.net/system//src/order/OrderProvList.cfm");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String result;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            a.append(inputLine);
            a.append("\r\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        result = a.toString();
        return result;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

This idea being that I can read in the HTML Source Code (the same code I see when I log into the system, right click on the page and select "View Page Source") and use the resulting string to extract things like order numbers, due dates etc for my applet.

I can successfully do this for SOME pages on this intranet system (the URL changes as you move from page to page) but not on others. I must be logged in to the system as a valid user for it to work.

On pages where this fails, the resulting HTML code seems to indicate my applet was redirected to some kind of log in page by JavaScript:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

        self.location='/system//src/Login.cfm?redirect=1';
    </SCRIPT>
```

I have double checked that I am logged into the system and that my applet is running under the correct user account. But for some reason it will only work for particular pages. Upon looking at the HTML source for the pages where this fails, it looks like there a particular piece of JavaScript that I'm guessing is the cause of this redirect.

My question is, is there a way to avoid this redirection - or is this Javascript there to prevent exactly what I am trying to do?

I have tried using Jsoup with followRedirects(false) and httpConn.addRequestProperty(...) options but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This could be based on how the security is implemented in the server. Sometimes it might be checking for the source. So you could try setting the referrer property or appropriate headers. If you are logged in properly it might work. For example.

```
String url = "https://www.internalsystem.net/system//src/order/OrderProvList.cfm";
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).referrer(url).get();
```